# open URL with iTunes via AppleScript on OSX

Tags: stream, applescript, itunes

I want to use iTunes to render a http mp3 stream on MacOSX. I understand the best way to remote control iTunes programmatically is AppleScript and I already can start iTunes, but:

1. what is the correct syntax to open a stream from a URL?
2. is it possible to keep iTunes invisible / hidden when running it via apple script? It always opens the GUI..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sending iTunes a command while it's not running will cause it to start up and display its default GUI; there's no easy way around that.

But if you want to force iTunes to hide, rather than keep it hidden if it wasn't already visible, you can do that:

```
tell application "iTunes"
  open location "your_url_here"
  play
  set visible of every window to false
end tell
```

Or, if you only want to hide iTunes if your script launched it, you can do something like this:

```
tell application "System Events"
  set iTunesWasRunning to count of (processes whose name is "iTunes")
end tell
tell application "iTunes"
  open location "your_url_here"
  play
  if iTunesWasRunning is 0 then set visible of every window to false
end tell
```

Of course there are some edge cases it doesn't handle (e.g., if iTunes was running, but the browser window was minimized, you will cause it to unminimize, and won't re-minimize it); look through the iTunes and System Events dictionaries and experiment with each edge case you care about. Also, there's a small race condition (if the user, or another script, happens to launch it after your check…), but there's not much you can do about that.

You don't actually need the "play" except in certain uncommon cases (e.g., iTunes is already paused on a stream), but it doesn't hurt.

Finally, by default, this will add "your_url_here" to a playlist called "Internet Songs" each time you run it, even if it's already there, creating the playlist if necessary. Hopefully you don't mind that; if you do, there are more tricks to learn.

Comment: great answer, thanks! I'd be interested in the "more tricks to learn" aka how to avoid the playlist from being created / changed.

Comment: It's the same kind of cheesy trick as hiding the window if you inadvertently made it appear. First get 'playlists whose name is "Internet Songs"'. After you call "add location", repeat. If there was no playlist before, and now there is one, delete it. (Or, if you just want to always delete it no matter what, just 'delete playlist "Internet Songs"' at the end of your script.)

Comment: Alternatively, IIRC, you can't change the visibility of a playlist after it exists, but you can create it invisible in the first place. I forget the exact syntax, but something like 'make user playlist with properties {name: "Internet Songs", visible: false}'. Do this before the first call to 'open location', and iTunes should start adding tracks to your invisible playlist instead of creating a visible one.

Comment: PS, have you been to dougscripts.com? Learning how to script an app from its dictionary is painful, especially if you're not an AppleScript wizard; having 400-odd examples to download and read over makes it a lot easier. (I never would have figured out how to get any of the "make" commands to work otherwise… and I never remember even now.)

Answer (score 2):

found the solution:

```
tell application "itunes" to  open location "your_url_here"
tell application "itunes" to play
```

it sill opens iTunes visibly but at least it's minimized.

By the way, I ran this from Java using (I believe this requires Snow Leopard though):

```
new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("AppleScript").eval("tell application ...");
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use QuickTime Player like answered here. Opens the same files, is preinstalled, and can be forced to use almost no visible GUI. It gets more complicated if you want another stream to start when one is finished though.

[play a stream in iTunes without adding it to the library / playlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12060827/play-a-stream-in-itunes-without-adding-it-to-the-library-playlist/13743077#13743077)